# Accessing Custom Outlook Calendar Entries

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I'm trying to access calendar entries from 2 custom Outlook calendars using Excel VBA.

I've obtained some code which gives me what I want from the default calendar but I cannot see how to change the location to my own calendars.

The code I'm using is

```
Sub ListAppointments()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olApt As Object
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim FromDate As Date
    Dim ToDate As Date
    
    FromDate = CDate("30/11/2021")
    ToDate = CDate("20/12/2021")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number > 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9)
    nextrow = 2
    
    With Sheets("Cal-Ext")
        .Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Date", "Start Time", "End Time", "Subject", "Location")
        For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
            If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then
                .Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)
                .Cells(nextrow, "A").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
                .Cells(nextrow, "B").Value = olApt.Start
                .Cells(nextrow, "B").NumberFormat = "HH:MM"
                .Cells(nextrow, "C").Value = olApt.End
                .Cells(nextrow, "C").NumberFormat = "HH:MM"
                .Cells(nextrow, "D").Value = olApt.Subject
                .Cells(nextrow, "E").Value = olApt.Location
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Else
            End If
        Next olApt
    
    
        Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9)
    
        nextrow = nextrow + 5
        For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
            If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then
                .Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)
                .Cells(nextrow, "A").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
                .Cells(nextrow, "B").Value = olApt.Start
                .Cells(nextrow, "B").NumberFormat = "HH:MM"
                .Cells(nextrow, "C").Value = olApt.End
                .Cells(nextrow, "C").NumberFormat = "HH:MM"
                .Cells(nextrow, "D").Value = olApt.Subject
                .Cells(nextrow, "E").Value = olApt.Location
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Else
            End If
        Next olApt
    
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    
    
    Set olApt = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I need to change the set olfolder command before the second loop to select my own calendar but nothing I've tried works.

**Outlook calendar**

[image]

**Current excel result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick code that I wrote to loop through all the navigation folders of **My Calendars**

This code was tested in `MS Outlook`. You may have to edit it for it to work in `MS Excel`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim oNameSpace As Object
    Dim oExplorer As Object
    Dim oMainFolder As Object
    Dim oCalModule As Object
    Dim oSubFolder As Object
    Dim oCalNavFolders As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objitem As Object
    
    Set oNameSpace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oExplorer = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(9).GetExplorer
    Set oCalModule = oExplorer.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(1)
    Set oCalNavFolders = oCalModule.NavigationGroups.Item("My Calendars").NavigationFolders
    
    For i = 1 To oCalNavFolders.Count
        Set objitem = oCalNavFolders(i)
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set oSubFolder = objitem.Folder
        On Error GoTo 0
                
        If Not oSubFolder Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print oSubFolder.Name
            If oSubFolder.Name = "Area1" Then
                With oSubFolder
                    '
                    '~~> Do what you want
                    '
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
            
            Set oSubFolder = Nothing
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code from Excel**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListAppointments()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim oNameSpace As Object
    Dim oExplorer As Object
    Dim oMainFolder As Object
    Dim oCalModule As Object
    Dim oSubFolder As Object
    Dim oCalNavFolders As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objitem As Object
    
    Set oNameSpace = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oExplorer = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(9).GetExplorer
    Set oCalModule = oExplorer.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(1)
    Set oCalNavFolders = oCalModule.NavigationGroups.Item("My Calendars").NavigationFolders
    
    For i = 1 To oCalNavFolders.Count
        Set objitem = oCalNavFolders(i)
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set oSubFolder = objitem.Folder
        On Error GoTo 0
                
        If Not oSubFolder Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print oSubFolder.Name
            If oSubFolder.Name = "Area1" Then
                With oSubFolder
                    '
                    '~~> Do what you want
                    '
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
            
            Set oSubFolder = Nothing
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Cant get this to work in excel - will keep trying but not sure what I've got to do yet

Comment: Posted the code that I tried from Excel and it works just fine...

Comment: This code runs for me until I try to add my bits then I get run-time 438 error object doesn't support this property or method.   It's probably something stupid I've not done but adding                       For Each olApt In oSubFolder.items
                        .Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)
                        .Cells(nextrow, "A").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
                        .Cells(nextrow, "B").Value = olApt.Start
gives me the error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "run-time 438 error object doesn't support this property or method"      It comes on the first of my commands to select data from an item    .Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and check the value of `nextrow` and `olApt.Start`

Comment: nextrow = 2 which is correct - set earlier in routine.  osubfolder = area1 which is correct so its looking in the right place.   olApt gives me nothing (not blank - no response)

Comment: That is strange because you cannot reach `.Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)` before crossing `If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then` If you entered the IF then it means `olApt.Start` is correct.

Comment: I hadn't put the date check into the code you supplied yet.  The .Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = CDate(olApt.Start) is the first time anything from the item is looked at

Comment: If I do put the check in - it passes the check.   There is the correct date in the olapt.start so it looks like it's the cell selection in excel that's wrong.   I'll play about a bit more now

Comment: It's working now :-)    Changed the .cells commands to range and I now have what I wanted.   Many thanks for the code you supplied Siddharth.  Couldn't have got there without you.

Comment: `.Cells()` will fail if it is not within a required `With/EndWith`. In your case `With Sheets("Cal-Ext")` Alternatively it would have worked if you changed `.Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)` to `Sheets("Cal-Ext").Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)`